# Why isn't this code behaving asynchronous

Tags: c#, system.reactive

As I understand Subscribe method should be asynchronous whereas Run is synchronous. But this piece of code is working in synchronous manner. Can anybody fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace RxExtensionsDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IObservable<int> source = Observable.Generate<int, int>(0, i => i < 10000, i => i + 1, i => i * i);

            IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe(x => { Console.WriteLine("Received {0} from source", x); }, ex =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured");

            }, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source said there are no more messages to follow");
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Asynchronous");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I always see Asynchronous written to console at the last.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed that `Subscribe` is always async.

Comment: and even if it is there's no guarantee that one thread will yield at any specific time

Comment: I figured that all I was missing was specifying Scheduler option: Scheduler.ThreadPool as the last one. Specifying that did the job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `Observable.Generate` uses `Scheduler.CurrentThread`. However, you can specify a different scheduler to get the desired asynchronous behavior:

```
IObservable<int> source = Observable.Generate<int, int>(
  0,
  i => i < 10000,
  i => i + 1,
  i => i * i,
  Scheduler.NewThread
);
```

The `Scheduler` class is in the `System.Reactive.Concurrency` namespace.

Other possible asynchronous predefined schedulers are `Scheduler.TaskPool` and `Scheduler.ThreadPool`.