# Asynchronous behavior in Observables Generator?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

Am starting with Reactive Extensions for .NET and was watching a DevCamp session video by Bart De Smet. I tried the following snippet which is supposed to be asynchronous -> the program flow should continue after subscribe but I don't see that happening. Here is the code snippet -

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   IObservable<int> o = Observable.Generate(0, i => i < 100, i => i + 1, i => i * i);
   o.Subscribe(x => { Console.WriteLine(x);});

   for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        Console.Write(k);

    Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

This always prints the squares of i first and then proceeds to the for loop. Is my understanding incorrect here? Or is it that the sequence of squares is already generated and hence it works through it?(the list of squares is already generated by the time it is subscribed to?)

Comment: `(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)` shouldn't be `for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)` ?

Comment: Brackets - Always use brackets. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was a duplicate of this a bit too late - [Why isn't this code behaving asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346811/why-isnt-this-code-behaving-asynchronous).

I would just like to add that the solution  mentioned there is deprecated now. You will get a warning, asking you to use NewThreadScheduler.Default from System.Reactive.PlatformServices assembly (instead of using Scheduler.NewThread from System.Reactive.Concurrency)